# Visualizing Decision Tree of K-Nearest-Neighbours classifier

Tags: scikit-learn, visualization, k-nn

I'm using Sklearn's [KNN](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html) to build a classifier and was wondering if there is any way to visualize the decision tree that the algorithm builds. Maybe something of this fashion

[image]

Comment: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#classification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$k$-NN does not build a decision tree to classify a new instance, it looks at the class of the most similar examples (the nearest neighbours) in the training set. So, in short, no you cannot get a decision tree from $k$-NN. You can build a decision tree for your dataset directly by using scikit-learn's `DecisionTreeClassifier` instead if you need a decision tree.

Comment: Ok, thank you. This explains a lot! I had this constant confusion that the K-nn is supposed to build a decision tree, but now I get it

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain dendrograms in other algorithms of clustering, concretely hierarchical clustering. May be you talk about that, it's not a decision, but have a similar appearance.